# delete a specific data in a array using php

Tags: php, html, css

Am creating a simple todo app. In that i want to user to delete a todo. i am trying to delete but it deletes the whole table. And also i try including row but it fails. can anyone help me to solve this?

table.php:

```
 <?php 
 include('connect.php');
$sql="SELECT * FROM tasks";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

$myArray = array(); 

echo "<table  style='width:80%;'>
<tr>
<th style='text-align:center;'>TaskName</th>
<th style='text-align:center;'>status</th>
<th style='text-align:center;'>Description</th>
<th style='text-align:center;'>DueDate</th>
</tr>";

$index = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{ 
 $myArray[$index] = $row;
 $index++;

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td style='text-align:center;'>" . $row['task'] . "</td>";
echo "<td style='text-align:center;'>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
echo "<td style='text-align:center;'>" . $row['description'] . "</td>";
echo "<td style='text-align:center;'>" . $row['due'] . "</td>";
echo "<td> <a href='delete.php'> <button class='btn  btn-default'>Delete Task</button></a></td>" ;
echo "</tr>";


}
?>
```

delete.php:

```
<?php
include('connect.php');

unset($myArray[$task]);

header("Location: dash.php");
?>
```

Comment: You're actually deleting the whole table. Try adding a `where` condition

Answer (score 0):

Pass a GET parameter representing a task ID to `delete.php`:

```
<?php
$task_id = (int) $_GET['task_id'];
// ...
mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM tasks WHERE id = $task_id");
```

where `id` is supposed to be a unique identifier (most likely a [primary key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database#Primary_key)) in `tasks` table. Then modify the view:

```
echo <<<EOS
<td>
  <a href='delete.php?id={$row['id']}'>
    <button class='btn btn-default'>Delete Task</button>
  </a>
</td>
EOS;
```

### Update regarding `unset`

Now you're trying to remove a task by `unset`ting an array item:

> ```
> unset($myArray[$task]);
> ```

Firstly, this will not remove anything from database. Undoubtedly, you need an ID (unique identifier) column in the tasks table! Without ID you are unable to clearly identify which row you want to delete. For instance, a declaration of a table with primary key in MySQL looks like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `tasks` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

For the table above you can insert items without specifying explicit values for `id`:

```
INSERT INTO tasks (name) VALUES ('something'), ('x');
SELECT * FROM tasks; 
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | something |
|  2 | x         |
+----+-----------+
```

Primary key protects from adding duplicate values:

```
INSERT INTO tasks (id, name) VALUES (2, 'abc');
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Then you can easily fetch or remove specific row by its ID:

```
SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE id = 2;
DELETE FROM tasks WHERE id = 2;
```

I hope you now understand the necessity of unique identifiers.

Finally, removing an array item is as simple as `unset($array[$item_key])`. I guess, you'll find the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) useful.

Comment: but i did not give id in tasks table. is there is any another way for that?

Comment: @Ram.k, you should add it, anyway. There should be an ID. Otherwise, you won't be able to remove them, at least.

Comment: yes i ad it to the table in the name task_id. and follows your code. But it delete the all todo's instead of deleting a single row

Comment: @Ram.k, it will work, if you run `"DELETE FROM tasks WHERE id = $task_id"`. If it removes all the rows, then you're wrong somewhere. I'll try to help, if you share the table structure (`show create table tasks`).

Comment: i  get my data into array.how do i delete element in a array by  index.

Comment: @Ram.k, looks like completely different question. Well, `unset($a[$i]);`

Comment: The code i use like:  $myArray = array(); $index = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{ 
     $myArray[$index] = $row;
     $index++; }. what i want to do if i want to delete one element?

Comment: @Ram.k, it is completely different question. Please ask in separate post. Besides, I've already answered - use `unset`.

Comment: ya i know unset() is to delete element. but i have a confuse in what element comes inside the unset($a[$i]); what is a and i ? so i shown my code to u.

Comment: i edit my que above please check and help me to solve the problem